# Problema con la decodificación de bytes a texto y comparación?

Tags: python-3.x

No entiendo por qué cuando abro un documento en formato de `bytes` con la función `open` y lo decodificas en texto, cuando lo comparas con una variable que contiene exactamente el mismo texto, `python` dice que son diferentes.

Pero eso solo sucede cuando el texto decodificado del documento tiene saltos de línea.

Ejemplo:

```
o = open('New.py','rb')

t = o.read().decode()

x = '''this is a
message for test'''

if t == x:
   print('true')
else:   
   print('false')
```

Aunque el texto decodificado `t` y el texto de la variable `x` son exactamente iguales, `python` los reconoce como diferentes e imprime en falso.

Incluso ya intente añadiendo `strip()` de la siguiente forma:

```
t = o.read().decode().strip()
```

Pero tampoco funciono.

¿Realmente he tratado de encontrar la diferencia de muchas maneras pero aún no entiendo en qué se diferencian y cómo puedo convertir `t` a igual `x`?

Comment: Sin el archivo para comparar no es fácil encontrar la causa. Haz `print(repr(t))` y muestra que te imprime.

Comment: @FJSevilla  Amigo, basicamente lo unico que hice fue copiar el texto de la variable  'x' asi tal cual como lo ves, lo pegue de un bloc de notas y lo guarde con extencion .py. Eso fue todo. Ayudame :(

Comment: En Windows se usa \r\n como fin de linea en vez de \n, puede ser una causa. Muestra la salida de repr, algo hay diferente aunque no lo veas a simple vista...

Comment: Tienes razon men, me imprimio ese maldito '\r\n' ... ¿que me sugieres ahora? si es un documento con muchas lineas como puedo convertirlo y que no pasen ese tipo de cosas amigo. Yo no conocia esa funcion repr() ni sabia que windows tenia ese problema

Comment: ¿Tienes necesidad de leerlo como archivo binario?

Comment: Te explico, el programa que debo hacer basicamente debe leer un documento binario con cualquier extencion ejemplo: .py, .doc, etc y debe generar las correcciones que se le envien desde una caja de texto de formulario de Tkinter . Asi que es importante que pueda cargar documentos tanto binarios como de texto. Por eso es importante para mi leerlo como binario y decodificarlo.

Comment: `t = t.replace("\r\n", "\n")` o `t = "\n".join(t.splitlines())` deberían valerte. Este último separa usando múltiples targets, mirate la documentación: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines. Si leyeras en modo texto al ser el argumento  `newline` de `open` `None` por defecto, cualquier fin de linea se traduce a `\n`, pero esto no pasa en modo binario.

Comment: Gracias, eres el unico que me ha dado alguna pista para resolverlo, te doy +10 puntos lince.  Los del stackoverflow en ingles ninguno ni siquiera se entero de como resolverlo.  voy a hacer pruebas haber que pasa. Saludos men.